# Specifiy type when converting from XML to JSON in MarkLogic

Tags: json, xml, marklogic

Using MarkLogic 8, I'm using a custom XML to JSON conversion for `json:transform-to-json`, and I've got it working just about right *except* the conversion is outputting numbers as strings.

Is there a way to specify that the value of a particular element should be a number value, not a string?

I don't see anything in the doc for [json:config](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:config), but just in case there's something I've missed, or if you have a neat post-processing trick, I'd love to hear about how to solve this problem.

Comment: Looks like the default strategy does the conversion the way you're looking for (`json:transform-to-json(json:transform-from-json('{ "value": 2 }'))`). Can you share a simplified version of your json:config that shows the problem?

Comment: I think that is because the default strategy (instead of the custom one), generates `json:basic` XML which probably comes with a built-in XML Schema. When converting arbitrary XML, you need to bring your own XML Schema..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by defining an XML Schema for the non-string type elements. Just make sure it is available in the context (by loading it into xdmp:schemas-database()), and that it is recognized (your XML needs to have a namespace that matches the XML Schema, and you might wanna use import schema)..

HTH!

Comment: followup a few years later for others who may be reading this.
There are good reasons to use encode xml 'numbers' as JSON 'strings' instead of 'numbers' -- YMMV.  JSON does not define the precision of the "Number" type, it is left up to the implementations.  Implementations usualy follow the JavaScript specs which use a 64 bit 'Double' for numbers, leaving only 54 bits of integer.  If you ever EVER expect its possible to get a number bigger then 54 bits, dont put it in JSON as a number.  (encoding as string is an easy alternative, there are others)